# How to write Files from a HTML File in a DropBox

Tags: html, browser, dropbox

My knowledge about Web technologies is very low and I just wanted to know if the following scenario would be possible with HTML5 and Javascript:

If I host an HTML file in Dropbox and send this link to seomeone, would it be possible that this HTML file creates a new file in my Dropbox? For exampe the HTML file is a form that one can fill out, can the HTML file create a text (.txt) file with the form content?

As far as I understand, the HTML file has to be hosted by a webserver and has to allow Javascript or PHP to achieve this. But maybe there is a way to just use an HTML file, a dropbox and a browser?

Any hints what topics I should study to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

On what I've understood from Dropbox, it does not directly show you the file contents in any manner. You can store files there, but the only thing you can see when opening a link that directs to the file, is the page which allows you to download the file to your own PC and save it.

This would seem like an impossible thing to achieve, in any cloud service like Dropbox it would seem. I would recommend you to just get the web hosting service, they are usually not that highly priced after all.

Comment: No, you can send someone a link to a public html file as a link, change the url to http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/yourfile.html, then you can open the html file in a browser...

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this, but you shouldn't. To make this work, you'd have to use the Dropbox API to upload files, and you'd have to embed in your web page an access token for your account. That means anyone who looked at the source of your web page could get access to make changes in your account (e.g. delete all your files). So there's no safe way to do this without a server-side component (like PHP).